# Cognitive Services | Translator |How To translate a website by implanting the code in it or through the url

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

During the development phases I had to work with service providers through sso, the use case here requires access to services, including iframes in dashboards, in this example for illustration:

```js
 let screenLog = document.querySelector("#screen-log");
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", logKey);

        function logKey(e) {
            screenLog.style.position = 'fixed';
            var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
            var tagNameIs = el.tagName.toString();
            var isIframe = tagNameIs == "IFRAME";
            var LangAtt = el.getAttribute("lang");

            screenLog.innerText = `
      Target Element : ${el.nodeType == 1 ? el : el.parentNode} 
      Target language : ${LangAtt}     
      Target Element Tag Name : ${tagNameIs}     
      Target Element direction : ${isIframe ? "Iframe ?" : el.style.direction == "" ? "Default" : el.style.direction}     
      Screen X/Y: ${e.screenX}, ${e.screenY}
      Client X/Y: ${e.clientX}, ${e.clientY}`;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        iframe {
            direction: rtl;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Hi ..., Welcom to Dashboard</h2>
    <p> <code id="screen-log"></code>
    </p>
    <iframe allowfullscreen width="100%" height="700" src="https://dropshipping.alibaba.com/"></iframe>
    <br>

    <p>Loading configuration....</p>
    <p>Done loading configuration</p>
    <p>Checking for valid pip....</p>
    <p>Done checking for valid pip</p>
    <p>Setting up specified environments....</p>
    <p>Environments successfully set up</p>
    <p>Checking for updates....'</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Automatically translating texts is a very tactful matter, especially with Microsoft Translator, so with the completion of a service, there is a privilege specific to this service, which is the possibility of converting the text direction from right to left In `AR`, this is with Edge Browser,

if this translator is translating the URL for Including it would be a solution for me that saves me a lot of time.
I chose to ask my question here because this is my last attempt and then I will close this file and look for more customized solutions.
I hope to get an answer.
Much appreciation.

Comment: Check this  [Use Azure Cognitive Services Translator APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/translator-text-apis?tabs=csharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Cognitive Services Translator to translate a website by either implanting code into the website or by using the URL.

You can use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/translator-text-apis?tabs=csharp) to call the Translator service.